# Add/Remove CSS Class on Route Change in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, css

I am not sure how this can be achieved in Angular. I want to add and remove CSS class on route change. I am trying to Show and Hide vertical menu. Currently I am using ui-route. Any Suggestion or link to example would be appreciated or any other suggestion on different approach to my problem is also welcome

Answer (score 3):

Easiest and most efficient way:

```
angular.module(...).run(function($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
});

<div ng-if="$state.contains('someState')">...</div>
```

This will remove the DOM which will improve performance if the menu has lots of bindings.

However, I constantly tell people to consider leveraging named views for navigation:

```
<body>
  <nav ui-view="nav"></nav>
  <div class="container" ui-view></div>
</body>

$stateProvider.state('home', {
  views: {
    'nav@': {
       templateUrl: 'nav.html'
     }
     '': {
       // normal templateUrl and controller goes here.
     }
  }
});
```

The cool part about this is that children states can override and control what nav file to use, and can even setup resolves and controllers that share data between the nav and the content. No directives/services needed!

Finally, you can do these too:

```
<nav ng-show="$state.contains('somestate')"></nav>
<nav ng-class="{someClass:$state.contains('somestate')}"></nav>
```

Alternatively checkout `ui-sref-active`

All of my suggestions primarily assume you're using UI-Router since it's the best!

Comment: I like this aproach by globalizing `$state`.

Comment: Great Answer :) Can you please create a Plunker for better understanding? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, fromState){

    if (toState.url === "/path") {
        $('div').addClass('className');
    } else {
        $('div').removeClass('className');
    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register the route changed and add this css to your DOM:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
     // Add your logic, for instance:
     $('body').addClass('hide-menu');
});
```

Obviously there are events raised before the route has been changed: "$locationChangeStart", [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location).

/***Edit***/ - Better approach

 Also I would rather using the ng-class attribute and simple bind a certain value from your main controller to it.

```
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.toggleMenu = function(isToShow) {
        $scope.isVisibleMenu = isToShow == true;
    }; 
});
```

then in your html:

```
<!-- Menu toggle button-->
<button ng-click="toggleMenu()"></button>

<div class="toggleable-menu" ng-class="{'visible-menu': isVisibleMenu}">
<!-- The menu content-->
</div>
```

and the simplest CSS possbile (you can obviously add animations or any other thing to toggle this menu.)

```
.toggelable-menu {
    display: none;
}

.toggelable-menu.visible-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I would normally steer people very clear of the practices described in this approach. You're using angular, you shouldn't be using jquery to mess with classes of the body tag. Secondly, messing with such a top-level DOM tag is superfluous for simply controlling navigation visibility. Thirdly, the answer doesn't address state-based toggling, you have a button which toggles a class. And although a class can be used, it's again potentially superfluous since ng-show or ng-if would suffice, but despite either case, you make no mention of $state-based checks.